# Why a CRT TV shows B/W noise when not tuned

Tags: noise

When an old  *color* tube TV with no relevant digital bits in it is not tuned to any TV station, the noise is black & white. Why is the noise not all RGB?

Comment: Duplicate: [Why is TV static noise always black and white?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/46401/why-is-tv-static-noise-always-black-and-white)